# Move filepond input to a different location in the DOM

Tags: vue.js, filepond

I'm in the middle of building the file uploading part of our system, and our design has two flows in which you can upload a file:

- Drag 'n drop onto the page
- Click the "Upload file" button which presents a modal.

If I drag 'n drop a file onto the page, I want to show a small popup in the bottom corner showing the upload progress of each file.

If I go through the modal, I get the option to drag 'n drop or browse files. It then shows me the same progress in the modal, however I have the option of closing the modal which should then show me that same small box in the corner with the upload progress.

From what I've been able to determine from the docs of FilePond, this doesn't sound like it would be possible. Every demo I've found links the FilePond instance to a single input and since it builds its own UI, the drop zone would also be built. Fine for the modal window but not for the full page drag 'n drop. So I have a couple of questions:

- Can I make anything a dropzone without it building the UI?
- If so, when I drop files can I specify where to display the uploading progress?
- Is it possible to move the progress from one area of the DOM to another (going from modal to the corner)?

I'm building this in Vue.j, so the plan was to use Vuex to manage the uploads and their progress which would make it easy to render the progress in different parts of the DOM. I love the look of FilePond for what it offers visually but if I can't get it to work with our designs then we may need to look at something else.

Comment: You can set `dropOnPage` to `true` and `dropOnElement` to `false` to have FilePond catch files dropped on the webpage. You can then use the available hooks to render a custom UI in the border of the view?

Comment: Can you specify what element the `dropOnElement` works on? So if I had a custom area instead of the whole page? And when you say the `border of the view` what do you mean by the border?